# Relate between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.

I have two tables, `table1.num` and *`*table2.num` in a database and I need to relate between them with a join query.

`table1.num` has prefix `DA`, like `DA-12929`, and `table2.num` has prefix `DB`, like `DB-12929`.

In my app, I have a join like

```
option = array(
                'recursive'  => -1,
                'fields'     => array('Table1.*', 'Table2.*'),
                'joins'      => array(
                    array('table' => 'table2',
                       'alias'       => 'Table2',
                       'type'        => 'INNER',
                       'conditions'  => array(
                            'Tabe1.num = Table2.num',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

How can I relate between them without prefix?

Answer (score 0):

HI i found a solution i just add SUBSTRING

```
option = array(
                'recursive'  => -1,
                'fields'     => array('Table1.*', 'Table2.*'),
                'joins'      => array(
                    array('table' => 'table2',
                       'alias'       => 'Table2',
                       'type'        => 'INNER',
                       'conditions'  => array(
                            'SUBSTRING(Tabe1.num,4) = SUBSTRING(Table2.num,4)',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
```